# UnicodeDecodeError at /success/ 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf7 in position 4: invalid start byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Не понимаю суть ошибки и почему она возникает. К слову, возникает она, когда я отправляю данные из формы на сервер. Попытался поменять кодировку файла и это не помогло. Также пытался поменять имя компьютера, что тоже не привело к результату.
views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError

def send_email(request):
    subject = request.POST.get('your-name', '')
    message = request.POST.get('tel-346', '')
    from_email = "youremail@mail.ru"
    print(subject)
    print(request)
    if subject and message and from_email:
        try:
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['youremail@mail.ru'], fail_silently=False,)
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')

    else:
        # In reality we'd use a form class
        # to get proper validation errors.
        return HttpResponse('Make sure all fields are entered and valid.')


def hello_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return send_email(request)
    else:
        return render(request, 'hello_page/main1.html')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите, где декодировали имя компьютера и в какой она кодировке.

Comment: я не совсем вас понял. Всмысле декодировал?

Comment: @Denis640Kb, могу только сказать, что пробовал менять кодировку на utf с BOM через notepad++ и вставлять в поле для замены имени компьютера. Это не помогло.

Comment: ну у Вас явно скрипт ругается на невозможность декодировать PC.mчто-то_там.w

Comment: дело в том, что там ничего быть не должно. я вставляю в имя компьютера PC, а он ругается на какие-то символы после PC, которые вообще неизвестно для меня откуда берутся.

Comment: и в трейсбэке в последней строчке видно, что имя компьютера PC

Comment: и мой вопрос по сути заключается в том, откуда берутся эти символы, и как их убрать

Comment: @Desertdeveloperа `даня` это что по-вашему?..

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 , простите, а где вы это заметили? Это имя пользователя на компьютере.