# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 46: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, django

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Последние статьи{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

     Блабла.....

{% endblock %}
```

файл base.html(ошибок там не было подсчитано):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}Мой сайт{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>

    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Возможно отсутствует BOM заголовок, из-за чего компилятор и редактор по-разному трактуют кодировку. Пересохраните правильно.

Comment: Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, укажите, пожалуйста все детали вашей ситуации (пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1065621/unicodedecodeerror-at-success-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xf7-in-position)